# How to import Markdown with Sphinx and myst-parser into Readthedocs?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, myst

In my `docs/source/conf.py` I have this code:

```py
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "myst_parser",
]
source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
```

All my files are in Markdown, not in reStructuredText.

On ReadTheDocs, the initial build was successful technically, only until the modules page was "not found" and the index page is completely blank.

My `.readthedocs.yaml`:

```yaml
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
   configuration: docs/source/conf.py

# Optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF
formats: all

# Optionally set the version of Python and requirements required to build your docs
python:
  version: "3.8"
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
      extra_requirements:
        - docs
```

My `setup.cfg` contains this:

```
[options.extras_require]
docs =
    sphinx
    myst-parser
```

Of course, doing `make clean html` in `docs/` works completely fine. Not sure why ReadTheDocs cannot properly link to the rest of the`.md` files from `index.md`.

Comment: Check the build log for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I checked the build logs, turns out I have some syntax errors (I did `list[str]` not `List[str]` with `from typing import List`)